# Simple network bandwidth usage tray icon

Tags: networking, internet, bandwidth, windows

When you use Process Explorer and minimize to tray, The icon turn itself in a graph of CPU utilization. I want to see that graph for network usage, specifically for internet usage. Example, I can download up to 100kb/s. I'm downloading an program at speed of 25kb/s, then I want see the graph with 25% of use of internet usage.

There is a simple and free program like this?

---

Edit
I've found an "revived" version of FreeMeter here:
[FreeMeter Revival](http://freemeterrevival.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this article that mentions FreeMeter Bandwidth Monitor For Windows (http://sourceforge.net/projects/freemeter/) and then several more in the comments.

> http://lifehacker.com/software/bandwidth/download-of-the-day-freemeter-bandwidth-monitor--windows-244649.php

Answer (score 4):

I like [NetMeter](http://www.metal-machine.de/readerror/index.php?page=10) it is free and works very well. It keeps track of your bandwidth useage so you can look back by day/week/month year. It also works with multiple NICs.